# GMLib -> GMPolygon -> Infowindow -> How to show it on center of Polygon?

Tags: delphi, gmlib

It is possible to show InfoWindow in center of Drawed Polygon?

I Draw Polygon but the infowindow showed on top of polygon. I want to show in center of polygon. Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  As stated in the guides, please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: No, because Google Maps API no provides a method to calculate it

Comment: I suggest to give your question a more descriptive title, people hunting for answerable questions won't be excited for a list of tags.

Comment: Thank you for answer Cadetill. I think coordinates of center of polygon is easy to known when using Getcenter - procedure GetCenter(LL: TLatLng);, but the problem for me is to set position of infowindow. Look this example:

Comment: this example: with gmpolygon1.Add do
 begin
  for x := 0 to strlistpoints.Count-1 do
  begin
   if (x mod 2 = 0) then addlinepoint(strtofloat(strlistpoints.Strings[x]), strtofloat(strlistpoints.Strings[x+1]));
  end;
  fillcolor := polyfillcolor;
  strokecolor := polylinecolor;
  fillopacity := polyopacity;
  visible := true;
  text := 'polygon 1';
  infowindow.HTMLContent := polyinfo;
  infowindow.CloseOtherBeforeOpen := false;
  if polyinfo <> '' then opencloseinfowin;
  sleep(100);
  zoomtopoints;
 end;

Comment: i can use opencloseinfowin to show it, but not set position of it. This is possible if i use GMinfowindow. There are is available procedure for position - Position (*) TLatLng TLatLng at which to display this InfoWindow.